# How to compile C code that is using kernel function in docker and use pci device in container?

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, linux-kernel, docker

I have a Makefile some C++ code that is using PCI device

```
all:
    g++ -o executable main.cpp dragon.pb.cc -std=c++11 -O3 -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/hiredis -lzmq -lprotobuf -lpthread -lpq -lhiredis


clean:
    rm executable
```

And It have dependencies on this C library that is using kernel functions. Makefile for this libraby is

```
    # dist and build are folders, not phony targets
.PHONY: all package clean

all: dragon.pb.cc dragon_pb2.py package

dragon.pb.cc: dragon.proto
    protoc --cpp_out=. dragon.proto

dragon_pb2.py: dragon.proto
    protoc --python_out=. dragon.proto

package: build

clean:
    rm -f dragon.pb.*
    rm -f dragon_pb*
    rm -rf build
    rm -rf dist
    rm -f MANIFEST
```

And here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

ENV PG_MAJOR 9.3

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y git make protobuf-compiler libhiredis-dev postgresql-server-dev-${PG_MAJOR}
RUN apt-get install -y g++
RUN apt-get install -y libzmq-dev
RUN apt-get install -y libprotobuf-dev
RUN apt-get install -y linux-headers-$(uname -r)
ADD deployment_key /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa


RUN echo "StrictHostKeyChecking no" >> /root/.ssh/config
RUN echo >> /root/.ssh/config
RUN echo "Host bitbucket.org" >> /root/.ssh/config


RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/
RUN git clone git@bitbucket.org:opticsdevelopment/dragon-protocols.git
WORKDIR ./dragon-protocols
RUN make dragon.pb.cc
RUN cp ./dragon.pb.* ../
COPY . /usr/src/app
WORKDIR ../
RUN git clone git@bitbucket.org:opticsdevelopment/dragon-module.git
WORKDIR ./dragon-module
RUN make all
WORKDIR ../
RUN make
EXPOSE 5570
CMD ["dragon"]
```

The problem right now is in installing linux-headers. Somehow it can't find headers

```
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-3.13.0-19-generic
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-3.13.0-19-generic'
```

Answer (score 3):

If your app can compile with any generic linux headers

In your `Dockerfile` change

```
RUN apt-get install -y linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

to just

```
RUN apt-get install -y linux-headers-generic
```

or if you need the same specific one as your host system
why dont you just volume link this directory from host to the docker container with the `-v`?

on your host system:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Now you have the kernel headers here: /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include

now on your **docker** container run command, link that volume like

```
-v /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include:/usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include
```